# CSS Vertically & Horizontally Center Div

Tags: html, css

I have a pop up which contains an ASP.NET form, click the link "Request Information" and the form appears.

However, the pages that have the link "Request Information" to trigger the pop up have a lot of content therefore scrolling is required to see the link.

I need to have the `div` always centered if a user scrolls to read the content, otherwise if they don't scroll the pop up still appears centered on screen.

The `div` is positioned absolutely, the whole page width is `960px` with margin set to `0 auto`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the div has an fixed width and height use:
(if width=120px and height=80px)

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px; /* negative half of the width */
margin-top: -40px; /* negative half of the height */
```

Comment: This puts the div down in the bottom right corner, not centered. You need to make to margins negative numbers.

Comment: they are negative now...

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense if you don't know the width and height of the box (that is the case in 95% of situations).

Answer (score 0):

Use a position:fixed; for this, use 0 for top, left, right and bottom, and give the div a display:table-cell; also, like this, setting text-align:center; and vertical-align:middle; will make everything inside appear exactly in the middle, without pixel-exact hacks like negative margins.

Comment: Ok and what values for left and top?

Answer (score 0):

If your popup div has a fixed size then you can use this CSS:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto; /* this requires a fixed size */
```

Otherwise you have to fiddle around with display: table-cell; and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/Hrwf8/

The key here is to set the left and top styles to 50% and set the margin-left and top to the negative amount of half of the width and height of the div. This of course requires that you have a fixed size for your div.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
.ClassCenter {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Source: 
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.html

Comment: That's only going to put the top left corner on the center, the box will still not be centered